# Image breaking its parent grid using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating some GUI using Tkinter and now after loading the image my child 'self.panel' grid which has image in it is increasing the parent grid which is 'self.top_left_frame_left_img_container'. Additionally, the image is adding some gray area which is not the part of the image. Could anyone help me with adjusting the image size according to its parent size excluding the gray space as well. The image should take the available space of its parent without breaking it.

```
def setImage(self):

    self.img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open(self.image_path))
    self.panel = tk.Label(self.top_left_frame_left_img_container, image= self.img)
    #self.panel.pack(side='top')
    self.panel.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, sticky='nsew', padx=2, pady=2)
    self.top_left_frame_left_img_container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.top_left_frame_left_img_container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight='1')
```

**GUI Before**
[image: GUI before]

**GUI After**
[image: GUI after]

Comment: The "before" image isn't showing up

Comment: @BryanOakley its working now.

Comment: We need a complete [mcve]. We can't just look at one column in isolation and know what the problem is.  Also, it's still not clear what you expect. Are the red and blue columns supposed to be a fixed size? What about the right column with the green and pink -- is that supposed to be a fixed size, or should it grown and shrink in proportion?